# Bash: remove all lines of input except last n lines

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I want to remove all lines except n last or first n lines with a short one-liner.

Example:

```
---

aaaa

bbbb

cccc

dddd

cat/echo/find ...  | sed < all except last 2 lines >
```

should result

```
aaaa

bbbb

---

aaaa

bbbb

cccc

dddd

eeee

ffff

cat/echo/find ...  | sed < all except last 2 lines >
```

should result

```
aaaa

bbbb

cccc

dddd

---
```

I need this also for a very high n. So it could possible to set n=100 or so.

Answer (score 6):

To **remove** the last 2 lines you can use something like this:

```
head -n $(($(wc -l < "$filename") - 2)) "$filename"
```

Not very elegant but it should work. I use wc -l to count the number of lines and then I use head to only display the first number of lines minus 2 lines.

EDIT: to **keep** only last `N` lines you could do

```
tail -n $N $filename
```

To **keep** only first `N` lines you could do.

```
head -n $N $filename
```

It seems I may have misunderstood your question and that is why I add these two commands.

Comment: `wc -l < $filename` will eliminate the need for `cut`

Comment: I would suggest you change back tics to parentheses like this: `head -n $(($(wc -l < $filename) - 2)) $filename`

Comment: Great for OSX users, where the `-n -2` syntax is not supported. One suggestion: to be safe, double-quote all `$filename` instances.

Answer (score 6):

From the head man page:

```
-n, --lines=[-]N
      print  the first N lines instead of the first 10; with the lead-
      ing ‘-’, print all but the last N lines of each file
```

which means `... | head -n -2` will do what you want.

Just as an alternative, the following also works, though I imagine its efficiency is not at all good for large files.

```
tac file | awk 'NR>2' | tac
```

Comment: Indeed the simplest solution; heads-up for OSX users: won't work there; use @Ivaylo Strandjev's answer there.

Answer (score 6):

> i want to remove all lines except n last

Easiest way is to do (let n=5):

```
tail -n5 $filename > $filename.tmp && mv $filename.tmp $filename
```

This will output last five lines to new file and than rename it.

If the task is opposite - you need all lines, but 5 last, you can to do:

```
head -n$((`cat $filename | wc -l` - 5)) $filename > $filename.tmp && mv $filename.tmp $filename
```

Answer (score 6):

To keep last 1000 lines of a file (Ex: alert_PROD.log)

```
tail -1000 alert_PROD.log > alert_tmp ; cat alert_tmp > alert_PROD.log ; rm alert_tmp
```

To keep top 1000 lines use head instead of tail command:

```
head -1000 alert_PROD.log > alert_tmp ; cat alert_tmp > alert_PROD.log ; rm alert_tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

To delete the last 3 lines of inputfile:

```
set 3 inputfile; sed "$(($(sed -n $= $2)-$1+1)),\$d" $2
```

Answer (score 0):

To print all but the first 3 and then all but the last 3 lines of a file:

```
$ cat -n file
     1  a
     2  b
     3  c
     4  d
     5  e
     6  f
     7  g
$ awk -v sz="$(wc -l < file)" 'NR>3' file      
d
e
f
g
$ awk -v sz="$(wc -l < file)" 'NR<=(sz-3)' file
a
b
c
d
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use head and tail：

To remove all lines except first n lines：

> head -n filename > new_filename

To remove all lines except last n lines：

> tail -n filename > new_filename

Here is an example:

$ cat test

1

2

3

4

5

6

7

8

$ head -2 test

1

2

Comment: you should provide a value for the -n option of both head and tail

Comment: Neither of these answers the question.

Comment: sigma you are still not solving the problem how to **remove** the last n lines. You say how to only display them

Answer (score -1):

You could also try

```
awk -vn=2 -f rem.awk input.txt
```

where `rem.awk` is

```
BEGIN { ("wc -l " ARGV[1]) | getline 
    a=$1-n+1 }     
NR<a { print }
```